# Как отключить Bootstrap в публичной части сайта, но оставить в админской?

Tags: yii2, yii-bootstrap

В приложении на Yii2 используется yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap библиотека.
Каким образом отключить использование bootstrap в паблике?
Если была бы верстка с отдельными файлами, все понятно, а как тут...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конфиге надо настроить assetManager

```
'assetManager' => [
    'linkAssets' => true, // Чтобы не создавались директории
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                'js'=>[]// css в таком случае будут подключены, если они есть в этом комплекте
            ],
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                'js'=>[]
            ],
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                'css' => [],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Можно настраивать более гибко. Например не публиковать ресурс по умолчанию, при этом подключить версию по внешней ссылке.

```
     'bundles' => [
            'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                'sourcePath' => null,   // не опубликовывать комплект
                'js' => [
                    '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js',
                ]
            ],
        ],
```

Можно подключать разные файлы в зависимости от окружения (DEV, PROD).

```
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                'js' => [
                    YII_ENV_DEV ? 'jquery.js' : 'jquery.min.js'
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Если мы настроим отключение ресурсов таким образом, то все зависимые ресурсы от этого также будут отключены и не опубликуются на странице.

```
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

Иногда возникают такие случаи, что в разных бандлах используются разные версии (например jQuery) скриптов. Чтобы не искать и не приводить все бандлы единому виду, для смены версии можно воспользоваться маппингом, как показано ниже. Таким образом все версии jQuery будут 2.1.1

```
    'assetManager' => [
            'assetMap' => [
                'jquery.js' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js',
            ],
    ],
```

Добавлять к каждому файлу комплекта ресурсов гет-параметр, который соответствует временной метке последнего изменения файла (обновление кэша браузера). Адреса файлов будут выглядеть так `/assets/5515a87c/yii.js?v=1423448645`

```
    'assetManager' => [
        'appendTimestamp' => true,
    ],
```

Код ядра Yii содержит большое количество комплектов ресурсов. Среди них, следующие комплекты широко используются и могут упоминаться в Вашем приложении или коде расширения:

- `yii\web\YiiAsset`: Включает основной yii.js файл который реализует механизм организации JavaScript кода в модулях. Также обеспечивает специальную поддержку для data-method и data-confirm атрибутов и содержит другие полезные функции.
- `yii\web\JqueryAsset`: Включает jquery.js файл из jQuery Bower пакета.
- `yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset`: Включает CSS файл из Twitter Bootstrap фреймворка.
- `yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset`: Включает JavaScript файл из Twitter Bootstrap фреймворка для поддержки Bootstrap JavaScript плагинов.
- `yii\jui\JuiAsset`: Включает CSS и JavaScript файлы из jQuery UI библиотеки.

Если Ваш код зависит от jQuery, jQuery UI или Bootstrap, Вам необходимо использовать эти предопределенные комплекты ресурсов, а не создавать свои собственные варианты.

В данном проекте у меня есть приложение api, frontend и приложение backend (админка). Вот в этом конфиге и надо добавить/изменить указанный код в секции components.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Благодаря такому гибкому механизму настройки ресурсов рекомендуется не подключать файлы скриптов и стилей напрямую в файлах представлений, а создавать классы, наследуемые от `AssetBundle` и регистрировать именно их.

Comment: А что при этом изменится, в лайауте или где? Как это отразится именно на выводе скриптов в том или ином лайауте/шаблоне, можете написать развернуто?

Comment: Можно добавить код и посмотреть. Если интуитивно непонятно.

Comment: Хорошо задам вопрос по другому, у нас есть "админка", "пупинка, что угодно дминка", у нас 25 видов админок, чем админка в данном случает отличается от паблика, я не вижу в этом коде, где указано для чего это отключит бутстрап...

Comment: В конфиге всего сайта надо это указать или для админки долен быть свой конфиг? вопрос тут сперва в этом...

Comment: Добавил скрин в ответ. Обычно есть конфиг для всего проекта и отдельный конфиг для каждого приложения. Конфиги приложений подключаются последними, поэтому с помощью них можно перезаписать данные предыдущих конфигов.

Comment: Еще дополнил ответ. Надеюсь теперь будет понятно что и где отключать, и каким образом это сделать. Кстати, в дебаг-панели можно посмотреть, какие ресурсы регистрируются на странице.

Comment: Тут такое дело, идем далее, я не понимаю откуда у вас бекенд и фронтенд каталоги появились? У меня только одна входная точка в приложение, может от этого я не понимаю почему одна входная точка в приложение и несколько конфигов?

Comment: Если я не вижу структуру, то вряд ли что-то дельное могу посоветовать. У меня фронт и бэк есть, потому что шаблон advanced.

Comment: Вот в этом то вся и проблема почему я не понимал что поменяет ваш код в конфиге, потому что у меня одна входная точка и я не могу понять как одна входная точка и несколько конфигов... Потому что сборка то у меня базовая

Comment: Как же тогда фронт от админки отделен?

Comment: Если уж все так плохо, надеюсь, что хоть разные шаблоны для фронта и админки. Поэтому в таком случае тоже можно отключить ненужные скрипты. Для этого надо создать свой бандл и добавить его в зависимость от стандартных скриптов фреймворка (для админки) и чистенький бандл для фронтенда, который не будет содержать зависимость от других скриптов.

Comment: Боюсь на пальцах я это не пойму точно...